# Access COM DLL from MBS Axapta 3

Tags: dll, com, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, ax

We have MBS Axapta 3 in our company. The boss doesn't want to migrate to a later version of Dynamics AX, so I'm stuck with this.

Basically what I'm trying is to access my own COM DLL from Axapta's X++ code. I would like to be able to access .net functions, so I've created my DLL using this tutorial:

http://www.softwareandfinance.com/CSharp/CS_ClassLib_Step1_CreateProject.html

The final code of my DLL is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ClaseCOM
{
    public class Test
    {
        [Guid("12D1EDAC-20C0-4faa-A774-B6F4C300B47E")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)]
        public interface IMathCtrl
        {
            [DispId(1)]
            int AddNumbers(int a, int b);
        }

        [Guid("282902B4-5FB9-461d-9CD0-FE8DD851F979")]
        [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
        [ProgId("SFTCSServer.MathCtrl")]
        public class MathCtrl : IMathCtrl
        {
            public MathCtrl() { }

            public int AddNumbers(int a, int b)
            {
                return (a + b);
            }

            public int MuliplyNumbers(int a, int b)
            {
                return (a * b);
            }
        }
        public static string ReturnString(string a)
        { 
            return "Ha enviado " + a;
        }
    }
}
```

After I generate the tbl, and register the dll with gacutil, I can call my dll from Axapta, but it doesn't recognize any method. It gives an error "method does not exist"

This is my x++ code:

```
static void DT_PruebasCOM(Args _args)
{
    COM PruebaCOM;
    COMVariant a,b;    ;
    PruebaCOM = new COM('ClaseCOM.Test');

// create variants to hold the arguments for the functions
    a = new COMVariant(COMVariantInOut::OUT, COMVariantType::VT_I4);
    b   = new COMVariant(COMVariantInOut::OUT, COMVariantType::VT_I4);

    PruebaCOM.ReturnString();
}
```

It gives the same error for AddNumbers and MathCtrl and IMathCtrl, so I don't really know if I need to setup something in order to make this methods visible in for the Axapta code.

Any ideas on how can I solve this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Your progid ClaseCOM.Test doesn't match SFTCSServer.MathCtrl

Comment: You code doesn't match your objects/methods either, ReturnString is not a method of the interface, etc. please update your answer if you need help. Your parameters shouldn't be OUT, please check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa854743(v=ax.50).aspx